# Diminuir valor de campo span com preg_replace

Tags: php, regex

Estou tentando alterar todos os valores dos campos que contém `span class`.

Exemplo o site está assim:

```
<div id="isOffered">
   <a class="price addBetButton footballBetButton" id="bk_82285689_mk_sel1" href="">
   <span class="priceText wide UK">1/2</span>
   <span class="priceText wide EU">1.50</span>
   <span class="priceText wide US">-200</span>
   <span class="priceText wide CH">1.50</span>
   <span class="priceChangeArrow"></span>
   <input class="betCode" type="hidden" value="0]SK@82285689@314222649@NB*1~2*0*-1*0*0]CPN:0" />
   <input class="originalBetCode" type="hidden" value="0]SK@82285689@314222649@NB*1~2*0*-1*0*0]CPN:0" /> 
   </a>
</div>
```

Qual a forma mais fácil pra mim recuperar os valores *1.50*, *200*, *1.50* e diminuir 20% do valor original utilizando da função `preg_replace`?

Comment: Queres fazer isso com PHP ou JS? se não sabes então pf explica melhor o que queres fazer... que funcionalidade.

Comment: Com PHP, usando a função preg_replace.

Comment: *1/2* entra? *200* entra como negativo?

Comment: Usar regex para analisar HTML [**é ceder ao apelo do chtulhu**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Como já mencionado na [**resposta do Tivie**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/51650/6454), expressões regulares não são recomendáveis para analisar uma estrutura como o *HTML*, além do mais ela não é uma [linguagem regular](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguagem_regular), não utilize *regex* quando há melhores ferramentas que possam fazer esse trabalho.

Leia mais sobre isso nesse artigo (em inglês): [**Expressões Regulares: Agora você tem dois problemas**](http://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/)

Vou seguir o mesmo caminho que o [Tivie](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/3854/tivie) e usar [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.domdocument.php) e [`DOMXPath`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.domxpath.php) para analisar o *HTML*, mas pode ser usado outro *parser*, como o [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) por exemplo.

```php
$url = "paginahtml.html";         // Link da página
$outputFile = "novapagina.html";  // Arquivo onde será salvo as modificações

$html = file_get_contents($url); // Pega o conteúdo da página

$DOM =  new DOMDocument();
$DOM->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DomXpath($DOM);

$prices = $xpath->query('//*[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), "priceText ")]');
$percent = 20.0 / 100.0; // 20%

foreach($prices as $price){
    $value = $price->nodeValue;
    $floatValue = floatval($value);
    $finalValue = $floatValue - ($percent * $floatValue);
    $price->nodeValue = $finalValue; // Salva o valor final com desconto de 20%
}

file_put_contents($outputFile, $DOM->saveHTML()); // Salva as modificações
echo "Done!";
```

<kbd>[DEMO](https://ideone.com/Wp19QE)</kbd>

O exemplo acima utiliza a função [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-get-contents.php) para obter o conteúdo da página e salva as modificações em um novo arquivo com [`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-put-contents.php).

O código funcionou como o esperado passando o link da página fornecida [nesse comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51643/diminuir-valor-de-campo-span-com-preg-replace/52121#comment106191_51650). A expressão utilizada na [`query`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/domxpath.query.php) vai retornar os resultados desejados se o *node* atual apresentar parte do nome do atributo *class*, nesse caso *priceText*, com a função [`normalize-space`](http://zvon.org/xxl/XSLTreference/Output/function_normalize-space.html) do [Xpath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp) substituímos espaços excedentes por um único espaço e assim validando a expressão.

Para exibir as modificações na tela pode-se usar o `echo`.

```
echo $DOM->saveHTML();
```

Answer (score 6):

Analisar HTML com regex é uma má opção [**e pode levar à loucura**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Existem muitas maneiras de regex falhar ao ler HTML (por exemplo, TAGS em maiusculas ou minusculas, espaços entre as classes, linhas extra entre os elementos html, etc...)

Regex significar "Regular Expression", expressão regular, e HTML não é uma linguagem regular. Invariavelmente vai quebrar algures...

---

Dito isto...

A melhor forma será usar um "parser" verdadeiro.  Felizmente, existem várias opções em PHP.

Aconselho a usar o [**DOMDocument**](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) e o [**DOMXPath**](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) que vêm incluidos no PHP por defeito. Eis um exemplo:

**HTML**

```
$html = '
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div id="isOffered">
       <a class="price addBetButton footballBetButton" id="bk_82285689_mk_sel1" href="">
           <span class="priceText wide UK">1.2</span>
           <span class="priceText wide EU">1.50</span>
           <span class="priceText wide US">200</span>
           <span class="priceText wide CH">1.50</span>
           <span class="priceChangeArrow"></span>
           <input class="betCode" type="hidden" value="0]SK@82285689@314222649@NB*1~2*0*-1*0*0]CPN:0" />
           <input class="originalBetCode" type="hidden" value="0]SK@82285689@314222649@NB*1~2*0*-1*0*0]CPN:0" /> 
       </a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>';
```

**codigo PHP**

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

//Lista de spans filhos de div"isOffered"->a
//So lista as divs que contenham a class 'pricetext'
$nodeList = $xpath->query("*/div[@id='isOffered']/a/span[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' priceText ')]");

foreach ($nodeList as $node) {
    if ($node instanceof \DOMElement) {
        // Le o valor do span e transforma num inteiro
        $value = (float) $node->nodeValue;

        // Altera o valor do span
        $node->nodeValue = $value * 0.8;
        var_dump($node->nodeValue);
    }
}

//salva as alterações feitas ao documenthtml
//e guarda na variavel newHtml
$newHtml = $doc->saveHtml();
```

Para impedir que o DOMDOcument engasgue em documentos HTML com erros, pode adicionar esta linha no inicio do seu codigo:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true) AND libxml_clear_errors();
```

Comment: Obrigado amigo! deu certinho.

Comment: Amigo, me dá outra força! seu código funciona, mas de onde estou retirando as informações, tem muitas div, tags e outras coisas, aí seu código não consegue capturar os valores e só me retorna "warnings", e outra: como faço pra levar esses valores modificados para o HTML? lembre-se que estou usando file_get_contents para pegas os dados de um site remoto e exibir no meu site da mesma forma, só que com os valores diminuidos.
desculpe minha ignorância, estou no começo do curso PHP e não sei muito ainda rs. por favor me dê mais essa ajuda!

Comment: Veja a ultima linha do meu post

Comment: Quanto ao capturar os valores, tem a ver com o XPATH, provavelmente tem de ser alterado para corresponder ao caminho de onde está a retirar a informação.

Aconselho a ler isto: http://www.dicas-l.com.br/arquivo/tutorial_xpath.php#.VO5WVfmsWxU

Pode ajuda-lo a compreender como funciona o XPATH, vai ver que é bastante simples. Depois é só substituir `"*/div[@id='isOffered']/a/span[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' priceText ')]"` pelo xpath correcto

Comment: Obrigado amigo! vou estudar o XPATH.

Comment: Quanto aos erros do  DOMDOcument, quando apliquei seu código no início, nenhum erro foi exibido, mas também não me mostrou os valores, ficou tudo branco. 
Se quiser ver como está o html que estou a buscar pode ir no link:
[link](http://admin.sportfacil.com/proxy/especial/valor.html)

Answer (score 3):

Também recomendo o uso do dom parser mas só pela diversão ta ai uma versão beta usando regex

```
<?php

$html = <<<XXX
<div id="isOffered">
   <a class="price addBetButton footballBetButton" id="bk_82285689_mk_sel1" href="">
   <span class="priceText wide UK">1/2</span>
   <span class="priceText wide EU">1.50</span>
   <span class="priceText wide US">-200</span>
   <span class="priceText wide CH">1.50</span>
   <span class="priceChangeArrow"></span>
   <input class="betCode" type="hidden" value="0]SK@82285689@314222649@NB*1~2*0*-1*0*0]CPN:0" />
   <input class="originalBetCode" type="hidden" value="0]SK@82285689@314222649@NB*1~2*0*-1*0*0]CPN:0" /> 
   </a>
</div>
XXX;

$re = "/(span.*pricetext.*>)([\d\/.-]+)/im";

$ret = preg_replace_callback($re, function($matches){
    $matches[2] = ((float)$matches[2]) * .8;
    return $matches[1] . $matches[2];
}, $html);

echo $ret;
```

https://ideone.com/4kEPf9

Comment: Cara o seu funcionou também! 
Obrigado pela ajuda :)

Answer (score 0):

E já agora uma resposta clandestina e pornográfica (Perl :)

com expressões regulares:

```
perl -pe 's/<span.*?priceText.*?>\K(.+?)(?=<)/$1*0.8/e' span.xml
```

Com parser de xml:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use XML::DT;
my $filename = shift or die("Erro: usage $0 file.html\n");

print dt($filename, 
            span => sub{$c *= 0.8 if $v{class} =~ /^pricetext/i; toxml },
            -html => 1,
        );

# $c - contents after child processing
# %v - hash of attributes
```